# Adding "Add New Record" and saving data to database using the Northwind example of the kendo grid odata application

Tags: kendo-grid

I downloaded and managed to get the northwind example of the kendo grid odata application working. I observed that whiles you can edit , read and delete data, you are unable to add new record. I have looked for an example of how to do this but all i have found have not solved this problem. Let me mention that i am very new to this kendo stuff